# How to access an array from the scope of a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope, this

I'm trying to add an element into an array with the push() method but apparently, I can't access that array from the scope of my function.

Here's a summary of my architecture :

```
class Test{
   myArray;

   aMethod() {

      Divs.forEach(
         ...
         let myElement = ...;
         div.addEventListener("click",

            function(){
               if(...){
                  this.myArray.push(myElement);
```

I know for sure that the **problem come from the array**.
When executing the code, I have an error telling me that push isn't a propriety of 'undefined'. Plus, on Visual Code Studio, when I click once on the "myArray" in the function, I see that it's not the same as the one that I declared at the top.

I've tried to declare it in various places but never successfully. I also tried to declare it like that `myArray = []`.

The strangest thing is that `myElement` **is accessible from the scope of this function**, so I tried to declare my array at the exact same place as so : `let myArray`... it didn't worked.

Does anyone see something suspicious ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I recommend moving your `click` event-listener function to a named function to make your code easier to see. I hope you're not assigning the event-listener more than once though.

Comment: Use an arrow function instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand how `this` works in JavaScript, I recommend reading [this & object prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/1st-ed/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes) for more details

This is a solution:

```
class Test{
   myArray;

   aMethod() {
      const myTestObj = this // store the Test instance in a variable myTestObj
      Divs.forEach(
         ...
         let myElement = ...;
         div.addEventListener("click",

            function(){
               // In here `this` is bound to the global object
               // because it will be invoked as a function, not a method, nor a constructor
               if(...){
                  myTestObj.myArray.push(myElement); // Use myTestObj
```

Another solution would be:

```
class Test{
   myArray;

   aMethod() {
      Divs.forEach(div => // Use an arrow function and only arrow functions in all the callbacks
        // In here `this` is bound to the same object as in the upper scope
         ...
         let myElement = ...;
         div.addEventListener("click",

            () => { // Arrow function here also
               // In here `this` is bound to the same object as in the upper scope
               
               if(...){
                  this.myArray.push(myElement); // Use this
```

Because [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) do not recreate a binding on `this`

Comment: Actually the first method worked well in my case, so thank you for that laruiss. I'll read that document to understand what happened.

Comment: Glad to help! Maybe you can accept the answer, then?

Comment: However, the second solution didn't worked, I couldn't manage to reference `this`even with the arrow function.

Comment: Of course ! I've also +1 but because my account is brand new, it won't show up soon... anyways, thanks !

Comment: I am pretty sure it should work as expected with the second solution... You used an arrow function also in the `forEach` callback, right?

Comment: Yes, actually my entire forEach line was already `caseDivs.forEach((div, index) => {` but I am convinced that this solution doesn't work because I've messed up something, not because what you say isn't true.